# Get all rows to the same format standard

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I currently have some rows that are not formatted properly. Essentially, I am storing chocolates in the following format XXXX CHOC00X. So, for example, in the list below Bounty CHOC001 is valid. But then any chocolates that don't follow this format are invalid. Please see list below:

```
Chocolates
Bounty CHOC001
twIX CHOC002
snickers CHOC003
Mars choc004
kinder Bueno ch0c005
dairymilk cHOc006
wisPa choC007
```

As you can see entries like `twIX CHOC002` and `kinder Bueno ch0c005` are invalid. I want something like this:

```
Chocolates
Bounty CHOC001
Twix CHOC002
Snickers CHOC003
Mars CHOC004
Kinder Bueno CHOC005
Dairymilk CHOC006
Wispa CHOC007
```

I tried using this formula `PROPER()` but then it only capitalises each word which is good by then `CHOC001` would then instead be `Choc001`. Not sure if there is a way to apply the same conditional formatting of the first column.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
={"Chocolates"; ArrayFormula(regexreplace(proper(A2:A8); "(?i)Ch(o|0)c"; "CHOC"))}
```

Change range to suit and see if that helps?

[image]

Comment: Nice and short. Please also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67033708/1527780) for a different, more general approach.

Comment: Thanks! What does the `"(?i)Ch(o|0)c"` bit mean?

Comment: (?i) makes the search pattern case insensitive. Ch(o|0)c means that Choc or Ch0c (with a zero) will match. More info: https://regex101.com/r/FQUQE9/1/

Comment: @JPV Thanks, I assume you first do `PROPER()` and then run the regex and finally using the regex change it to `CHOC`?

Comment: @JPV I guess what I am trying to get my head around is how you are extracting the numbers at the end, i.e. `001, 002, 003 etc`?

Comment: I don't do anything with the numbers. Just replacing all variations of 'choc'  (or ch0c) with CHOC.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution

```
={"Chocolates "; 
   INDEX(IFERROR(PROPER(REGEXEXTRACT(F2:F,"(.+:?\w+ )"))&
                  "CHOC"&REGEXEXTRACT(F2:F,"(\d+$)")))}
```

[image]

- `"(.+:?\w+ )"` get everything until before last space
- `"(\d+$)"` get digits from end and add before them `CHOC`