# How to remove blank rows in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was wondering if there was a way to quickly remove blank rows using a formula like `COUNTA`?

I have something like this with blanks:

```
Chocolates
Bounty CHOC001
Twix CHOC002


Snickers CHOC003

Mars CHOC004

Kinder Bueno CHOC005

Dairymilk CHOC006

Wispa CHOC007
```

Now I want it to be like this with blanks removed:

```
Chocolates
Bounty CHOC001
Twix CHOC002
Snickers CHOC003
Mars CHOC004
Kinder Bueno CHOC005
Dairymilk CHOC006
Wispa CHOC007
```

Thanks

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @IanCampbell okay mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the list is in column A, you can try

```
=filter(A2:A10, len(A2:A10))
```

[image: Example]

If you want to incorporate this in the formula I provided [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67032350/get-all-rows-to-the-same-format-standard/67033498?noredirect=1#comment118493424_67033498), you can try

```
={"Chocolates"; query(ArrayFormula(regexreplace(proper(A2:A10), "(?i)ch(o|0)c", "CHOC")), "where Col1 <>''",0)}
```

[image]